# TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, list found in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Below python method is giving error 'TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, list found'

```
def read_csv(filename):
    test_data = []
    with open(filename, newline="") as csvfile:
        data = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(data)  # skip header row
        for row in data:
            test_data.append(row)

        return test_data
```

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre] and full traceback you get

Comment: What's the exact traceback? I don't see what in this code could raise that error.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit unclear, i'm not sure why you mention pytest. More context would be nice.

For the time being, you can try to specify the encoding when opening the file.

```py
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs because the `str()` function is intended to be used to decode `bytes` objects to strings, not `lists`.

To fix this error, you will need to use a different approach to convert the `list` to a `string`. One way to do this is to use the `join()` method of strings, which allows you to join the elements of a `list` into a single `string`.